# Pole Placement of dynamics systems

Tags: control-theory

In the pole allocation problem, for a dynamic system instead of allocating the poles to obtain the natural total overshoot and setting line of the system, specify these specifications individually for each pole? For example, considering a third order system, the real pole will have a overshoot and setting line and the two conjugated complex poles will have a distinct overshoot and setting line. That is, I allocate the poles so that they have different specifications, I am not concerned with the total system specifications.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How damping ratio and natural frequency influence overshoot and system time specifications system. For second order systems there are formulations to obtain these specifications, but for higher order systems how to obtain these specifications?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to calculate the overshoot of a general transfer function.